# how to place an image behind a div

Tags: css

[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJan.png)

I have the black div first, then I have the purple div, lastly I have the image as a child of the purple div

I'm trying to get the black div to be above the part of the image that's overlayed on it so it can look like this:

[what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjCS1.png)

how do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried overflow: hidden on the purple div? If you could give us a runnable snippet we could give better advice. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you can `::before` CSS Pseudo-element for balck box and put it on top of div using absoluted div.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 9;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
```